# React re-render App component after push state

Tags: reactjs

I've got a react container and outwith that I've got main navigation. I want my main navigation to be able to control the react app within the container when a link is clicked. My thinking is, when a link is clicked, to push the HREF value to the address bar (pushState) then re-render hoping that React will recognise the new URL and render accordingly. Below is my attempt:

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

// when each link is clicked, push state and re-render React app 
const links = document.getElementById("page").getElementsByTagName("A");
for (let i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

  links[i].addEventListener("click", e => {

    // push the route to address bar 
    history.replaceState(null, null, e.target.getAttribute("href"));

    // call render 
    render(
      <App/>,
      document.getElementById('react-app')
    );

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  })
};
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <nav class="navbar ..">
      [.. main nav links ..]
    </nav>
    
    <div id="react-app">
      [.. here is where will be re-rendered ..]
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

However, it seems to work the first time, but not again. I'm guessing that the new route in after the pushState isn't picked up? Or the render call doesn't do anything as the component has already been attached?

Comment: why not use  react route and link?

Comment: Why do you put render in for loop ?

Comment: @Martyn - Why not using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) ?

Comment: @Martyn - If you don't want to use any router, I suggest you use buttons instead, clicking on it will change the state, then choose what to render depending on the state

Comment: @ridoansaleh - It's actually in the callback of events-listeners, set in a loop

Comment: I'm attempting progressive decoupling and will have parts of the page that are rendered by the CMS, it's not an SPA.

Comment: @Martyn - Can you try to put a `console.log` inside the for loop ? I think the loop is executed only at the first render, but not when you re-render